# Implicit conversions are failing in generics

Tags: c#, generics

```
    public class ExternalUserService : ServiceBase<ExternalUser>, IServiceBase<ExternalUser>, IDisposable
        {
            public ExternalUserService():base()
            {enter code here

            }

            public ExternalUserService(IBusinessEntityMap entityMap,string ConnectionString)
            {
                repository = new BusinessModelRepository(typeof(ExternalUserMap), ConnectionString);
        }
    }

 [ServiceContract(ConfigurationName = "IServiceBase", Namespace = "http://xyz.com")]

    public interface IServiceBase<TEntity> where TEntity : BusinessEntityBase<TEntity>, new()
    {
        [OperationContract]
    }

 [DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class ExternalUser : BusinessEntityBase<ExternalUser>
    {
//some entity work
        }
```

> I'm trying to write service host factory so that I can have single host and based on entity. So that I can have one host. something like

```
<%@ ServiceHost Factory="Service.BaseServiceFactory`1[BusinessEntityBase<ExternalUser>,IServiceBase<ExternalUser>,ExternalUser]"
```

Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Some generic service"%>

```
public class BaseServiceFactory<x,y,z> : ServiceHostFactory
       where x : BusinessEntityBase<y>,new()
        where z : IServiceBase<x>
        where y : class,new()
    {

        protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {


            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
            ServiceEndpoint endpoint = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(z), new BasicHttpBinding(), "");

            return host;
        }
    }

 public abstract class BusinessEntityBase<TEntity> : IBusinessEntity<TEntity>
        where TEntity : class, new()
    {
}
```

I get below error on line 10 (declaration of BaseServiceFactory class).

The type 'x' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'Service.IServiceBase'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'x' to 'BusinessModel.BusinessEntityBase'. D:\Service\BaseServiceFactory.cs    10  18  Security.Service

Comment: Which line is line 84? And where is class IFusionServiceBase?  It doesn't seem that the code you've posted matches the error message.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I corrected it. the error is at the at line 10 (declaration of BaseServiceFactory class). also, I had edited the actual namespaces. so it's iservicebase. corrected the error message too.(84 wasn't a line number. it was a sl.no. removed it)